# "chkdsk /r" to confirm no error OR "chkdsk /f" to avoid heavy loading to HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, chkdsk, dism, sfc

Recently I got "Reallocation Event Count" (C4) warning in SMART test for my notebook harddisk(HDD). I've cloned the whole HDD sector-by-sector to a brand new one using a external HDD docking.

Then I ran chkdsk (`chkdsk C: /r /i`) for my new HDD at bootup, it reported that some errors in files were found and all errors were fixed. No further action is required.

Then I can enter Windows and ran `sfc /scannow` as a double check. But it surprisingly reported that some files still contain errors, even after chkdsk said all errors were fixed. I then used DISM.exe to fix and ran `sfc /scannow` again. This time no error was found anymore.

As my previous chkdsk skips checking index files (`/i` switch), I'm not sure if this causes the outstanding errors. Now I want to run chkdsk again to confirm 100% that no more error exists (at least in current stage).

**Should I run `chkdsk C: /r` to confirm no error without the worries behind?

Or running `chkdsk C: /f` is enough to verify and also can avoid heavy loading to HDD?**

*PS: There is a saying that running `/r` switch will heavily read and write HDD, which causes temperature of HDD increases. Due to thermal expansion and contraction, the magnetic head of HDD may be too close to the magnetic disk to damage it.*

Comment: I always run chkdsk with no switches, it runs but does not correct anything but still gives a report on what it finds, then I run it with switches if there are issues. I don't see why you use the i switch. That saying is nonsense.

Comment: Unless you run chkdsk /R 20+ times a week the temperature and thermal expansion/contraction are non issues.  **chkdsk /R** only reads all available sectors, but does very little writing.

Comment: @Moab I used /i switch because I guessed there should be no errors for brand new HDD, and this switch will skip scanning index files, reducing the waiting time. But I did find error after `chkdsk /r /i`, so I should have used chkdsk without /i to scan completely

Comment: @cybernard I have over 700k small files in my 1TB HDD, I'm worried that `chkdsk /r` will be quite heavy to my HDD since I've already run chkdsk once....